# ASP.Net OutputCache: User Controls That Are Cached

Tags: asp.net, outputcache, user-controls

Is there a way to obtain a list of User Controls (an/or instances of user contols) that have been cached? The Cache object's collection doesn't seem to include OutputCached items. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a wrapper around outputcache and store objects in outputcache programmatically instead of declaratively within the controls. This way you can control the complete collection of cached items and at any given point of time, get whatever details you need about the cached items.

you can implement outputcaching programmatically using the [article here](http://blogs.technet.com/stefan_gossner/archive/2005/07/11/407522.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Vikram. Just to make sure I am understanding you clearly, are you hinting that there is No means to get at the OutputCached items using the standard mechanisms? Thanks again.

Comment: as far as i know, there is no inbuilt mechanism to find that out.